# Why does my Datastax Spark app use unusual amounts of memory?

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, datastax, datastax-enterprise

My systems memory is 32GB.  I currently have 3 machines and 1 machine already has 4GB another only 10GB and another 14GB which is constantly decreasing. Now my system has run for 44 hours and the memory usage is very high already and keeps increasing, which will lead to a crash.

This is my spark executor picture:

[image]

This is my pyspark code which uses more and more memory the longer it runs, which I don't want because my system will crash. Any suggestions on how to change this?:

```
begin = datetime.now(tz)
print 'begin:%s' % (begin)

article_channels = articlestat.join(channels).map(lambda x:(x[1][0]['id'],{'id':x[1][0]['id'],'thumbnail':x[1][0]['thumbnail'],'title':x[1][0]['title'],'url':x[1][0]['url'],'created_at':x[1][0]['created_at'],'source':x[1][0]['source'],'category':x[1][0]['category'],'author':x[1][1]['name']}))

speed_rdd = axes.map(lambda x:(x.article,[[x.at,x.comments,x.likes,x.reads,x.shares]])) \
            .reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y) \
            .filter(lambda x:len(x[1])>=2) \
            .map(lambda x:(x[0],sorted(x[1],key=lambda y:y[1],reverse = True)[0],sorted(x[1],key=lambda y:y[1],reverse = True)[1])) \
            .filter(lambda x:(x[1][0]-x[2][0]).seconds>0) \
            .map(lambda x:(x[0],{'id':x[0],'comments':x[1][1],'likes':x[1][2],'reads':x[1][3],'shares':x[1][4],'speed':5*300*((x[1][1]-x[2][1])/((x[1][0]-x[2][0]).seconds/60.0))})) \
            .filter(lambda x:x[1]['comments']>0)

statistics = article_channels.join(speed_rdd)  \
            .map(lambda x:{'id':x[1][0]['id'],'thumbnail':x[1][0]['thumbnail'],'title':x[1][0]['title'],'url':x[1][0]['url'],'created_at':x[1][0]['created_at'],'source':x[1][0]['source'],'category':x[1][0]['category'],'author':x[1][0]['author'],'comments':x[1][1]['comments'],'likes':x[1][1]['likes'],'reads':x[1][1]['reads'],'shares':x[1][1]['shares'],'speed':x[1][1]['speed']})


timeone=datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)
timethree = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=3)
timesix = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=6)
timetwelve = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=12)
timetwentyfour = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=24)

result1 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timeone).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='1',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at'],genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
result3 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timethree).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='3',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at'],genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
result6 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timesix).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='6',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at'],genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
result12 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timetwelve).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='12',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at'],genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
result24 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timetwentyfour).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='24',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at'],genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))

if result1.count()>0:
    print 'result1 insert=======>',result1.take(1)
    session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'1'))
    resultschema1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result1)
    resultschema1.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="statistics", keyspace = "statistics").save(mode ="append")
if result3.count()>0:   
    print 'result3 insert=======>',result3.take(1)
    session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'3'))
    resultschema3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result3)
    resultschema3.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="statistics", keyspace = "statistics").save(mode ="append")

if result6.count()>0:
    print 'result6 insert=======>',result6.take(1)
    session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'6'))
    resultschema6 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result6)
    resultschema6.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="statistics", keyspace = "statistics").save(mode ="append")

if result12.count()>0:
    print 'result12 insert=======>',result12.take(1)
    session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'12'))
    resultschema12 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result12)
    resultschema12.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="statistics", keyspace = "statistics").save(mode ="append")

if result24.count()>0:
    print 'result24 insert=======>',result24.take(1)
    session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'24'))
    resultschema24 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result24)
    resultschema24.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="statistics", keyspace = "statistics").save(mode ="append")
end = datetime.now(tz)
print 'timeone:%s  timethree:%s timesix:%s timetwelve:%s timetwentyfour:%s' % (timeone,timethree,timesix,timetwelve,timetwentyfour)
print 'all is done==================================:time:%s' % (datetime.now(tz))
print 'TOTAL TIME IS:%s seconds' % ((end-begin).seconds)
```

EDIT:

This is my code which has 2 parts. 
1) Reading messages from Kafka and saving them to Cassandra. 
2) Reading data from Cassandra and then analyzing the data and afterwards saving the analyzed data back to Cassandra.

```
import sys
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, rddsampler
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import OffsetRange, KafkaUtils, TopicAndPartition
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
from dateutil.parser import parse 
import pickle
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from expiringdict import ExpiringDict
import pytz
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
tz = pytz.timezone('')
appname = str(sys.argv[1])
source = str(sys.argv[2])
cluster = Cluster(['localhost']);
session_statis = cluster.connect('keyspace')
def read_json(x):
    try:
        y = json.loads(x)
    except:
        y = 0
    return y
def categoryTransform(x):
    try:
        body = json.loads(x['body'])
        return (body['article'])
    except:
        return 0
def TransformInData(x):
    try:
        body = json.loads(x['body'])
        return (body['articles'])
    except:
        return 0
def axesTransformData(x):
    try:
        body = json.loads(x['body'])
        body['id'] = x['attrs']['id']
        return (body)
    except:
        return 0

def articleInCache(rdd):
    rdd_channel=rdd.map(lambda x:(x[1]['channel'],{'id':x[0],'title':x[1]['title'],'thumbnail':x[1]['thumbnail'],'url':x[1]['url'],'created_at':x[1]['created_at']})) \
        .join(channels).map(lambda x:{'id':x[1][0]['id'],'title':x[1][0]['title'],'thumbnail':x[1][0]['thumbnail'],'url':x[1][0]['url'],'created_at':x[1][0]['created_at'],'author':x[1][1]['name']})
    rdd_cassandra = rdd.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[0],x[1]['thumbnail'] if x[1]['thumbnail'] else '',x[1]['title'],x[1]['url'],datetime.strptime(parse(x[1]['created_at']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")+timedelta(hours=8),source,x[1]['category'] if x[1]['category'] else '',x[1]['channel']))) \
                        .subtract(articles)
    rdd_article = rdd_cassandra.map(lambda x:Row(id=x[1][0],source=x[1][5],thumbnail=x[1][1],title=x[1][2],url=x[1][3],created_at=x[1][4],category=x[1][6],channel=x[1][7]))
    rdd_schedule = rdd_cassandra.map(lambda x:Row(source=x[1][5],type='article',scheduled_for=x[1][4]+timedelta(minutes=5),id=x[1][0]))
    rdd_article_by_created_at = rdd_cassandra.map(lambda x:Row(source=x[1][5],created_at=x[1][4],article=x[1][0]))
    rdd_article_by_url = rdd_cassandra.map(lambda x:Row(url=x[1][3],article=x[1][0]))
    if rdd_article.count()>0:
        result_rdd_article = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_article)
        result_rdd_article.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")
    if rdd_schedule.count()>0:   
        result_rdd_schedule = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_schedule)
        result_rdd_schedule.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")
    if rdd_article_by_created_at.count()>0:  
        result_rdd_article_by_created_at = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_article_by_created_at)
        result_rdd_article_by_created_at.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")
    if rdd_article_by_url.count()>0:   
        result_rdd_article_by_url = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_article_by_url)
        result_rdd_article_by_url.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")



def categoryInCache(x):
    article_update=articles.join(x).map(lambda x:Row(id=x[1][0][0],source=x[1][0][5],thumbnail=x[1][0][1],title=x[1][0][2],url=x[1][0][3],created_at=x[1][0][4],category=x[1][1]['category'],channel=x[1][0][7]))
    if article_update.count()>0:
        result_article_update = sqlContext.createDataFrame(article_update)
        result_article_update.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")

def axesInCache(rdd):
    if rdd.count()>0:
        axes_rdd=rdd.map(lambda x:Row(article=x[0],at=datetime.strptime(parse(x[1]['at']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")+timedelta(hours=8),comments=x[1]['comments'],likes=x[1]['likes'],reads=0,shares=0))
        axesresult = sqlContext.createDataFrame(axes_rdd)
        axesresult.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")
def statistics(rdd):
    article_channels = articlestat.join(channels).map(lambda x:(x[1][0]['id'],{'id':x[1][0]['id'],'thumbnail':x[1][0]['thumbnail'],'title':x[1][0]['title'],'url':x[1][0]['url'],'created_at':x[1][0]['created_at'],'source':x[1][0]['source'],'category':x[1][0]['category'],'author':x[1][1]['name']}))
    speed_rdd = axes.map(lambda x:(x.article,[[x.at,x.comments,x.likes,x.reads,x.shares]])) \
                .reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y) \
                .map(lambda x:(x[0],sorted(x[1],key=lambda y:y[0],reverse = True)[0],sorted(x[1],key=lambda y:y[0],reverse = True)[1]) if len(x[1])>=2 else (x[0],sorted(x[1],key=lambda y:y[0],reverse = True)[0],[sorted(x[1],key=lambda y:y[0],reverse = True)[0][0]-timedelta(seconds=300),0,0,0,0])) \
                .filter(lambda x:(x[1][0]-x[2][0]).seconds>0) \
                .map(lambda x:(x[0],{'id':x[0],'comments':x[1][1],'likes':x[1][2],'reads':x[1][3],'shares':x[1][4],'speed':5*300*((x[1][1]-x[2][1])/((x[1][0]-x[2][0]).seconds/60.0))})) \
                .filter(lambda x:x[1]['comments']>0)
    statistics = article_channels.join(speed_rdd)  \
                .map(lambda x:{'id':x[1][0]['id'],'thumbnail':x[1][0]['thumbnail'],'title':x[1][0]['title'],'url':x[1][0]['url'],'created_at':x[1][0]['created_at'],'source':x[1][0]['source'],'category':x[1][0]['category'],'author':x[1][0]['author'],'comments':x[1][1]['comments'],'likes':x[1][1]['likes'],'reads':x[1][1]['reads'],'shares':x[1][1]['shares'],'speed':x[1][1]['speed']})
    timeone=datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)
    timethree = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=3)
    timesix = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=6)
    timetwelve = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=12)
    timetwentyfour = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=24)
    result1 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timeone).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='1',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8),genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
    result3 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timethree).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='3',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8),genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
    result6 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timesix).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='6',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8),genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
    result12 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timetwelve).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='12',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8),genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
    result24 = statistics.filter(lambda x:x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8)>=timetwentyfour).map(lambda x:Row(timespan='24',source=source,id=x['id'],title=x['title'],thumbnail=x['thumbnail'],url=x['url'],created_at=x['created_at']+timedelta(hours=8),genre='',reads=0,likes=x['likes'],comments=x['comments'],shares=x['shares'],speed=x['speed'],category=x['category'],author=x['author']))
    if result1.count()>0:
        session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM tablename WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'1'))
        resultschema1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result1)
        resultschema1.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")
    if result3.count()>0:   
        session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM tablename WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'3'))
        resultschema3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result3)
        resultschema3.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")

    if result6.count()>0:
        session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'6'))
        resultschema6 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result6)
        resultschema6.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")

    if result12.count()>0:
        session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'12'))
        resultschema12 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result12)
        resultschema12.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")

    if result24.count()>0:
        session_statis.execute('DELETE FROM statistics WHERE source = %s and timespan= %s', (source,'24'))
        resultschema24 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result24)
        resultschema24.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace = "keyspace").save(mode ="append")
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appname)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,30)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
channels = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","tablename").map(lambda x:(x.id,{'name':x.name}))
articles = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","tablename").map(lambda x:(x.id,(x.id,x.thumbnail,x.title,x.url,x.created_at+timedelta(hours=8),x.source,x.category,x.channel)))
articlestat = sc.cassandraTable('keyspace','tablename').map(lambda x:(x.channel,{'id':x.id,'thumbnail':x.thumbnail,'title':x.title,'url':x.url,'created_at':x.created_at,'source':x.source,'category':x.category,'channel':x.channel}))
axes = sc.cassandraTable('keyspace','tablename')
topic = 'topic'
kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"}
category = 'category_topic'
category_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [category], kafkaParams)
category_join_stream = category_stream.map(lambda x:read_json(x[1])).filter(lambda x:x!=0).map(lambda x:categoryTransform(x)).filter(lambda x:x!=0).map(lambda x:(x['id'],x))
category_join_stream.transform(categoryInCache).pprint()
article_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], kafkaParams)
article_join_stream=article_stream.map(lambda x:read_json(x[1])).filter(lambda x: x!=0).map(lambda x:TransformInData(x)).filter(lambda x: x!=0).flatMap(lambda x:(a for a in x)).map(lambda x:(x['id'].encode("utf-8") ,x))
article_join_stream.transform(articleInCache).pprint()
axes_topic = 'axes_topic'
axes_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [axes_topic], kafkaParams)
axes_join_stream = axes_stream.filter(lambda x:'delete' not in str(x)).map(lambda x:read_json(x[1])).filter(lambda x: x!=0).map(lambda x:axesTransformData(x)).filter(lambda x: x!=0).map(lambda x:(str(x['id']),x))#.map(lambda x:(x[0],{'id':x[0], 'attitudes':x[1]['likes'],'reposts':0,'comments':x[1]['comments'],'speed':x[1]['comments']}))
axes_join_stream.transform(axesInCache).pprint()
stat = article_join_stream.map(lambda x:x['id']).window(5*60,5*60)
stat.transform(statistics).pprint()
ssc.start()    # Start the computation ssc.awaitTermination()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: Where are you reading the data from?

Comment: from kafka and cassandra

Comment: Could you add that code as well?

Comment: I just updated the code you requested as well. Thanks

Comment: could you have a look at this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889361/why-is-my-spark-streaming-app-so-slow thanks!